# tkinter's columnconfigure method(s)?

Tags: tkinter, grid

Are there any differences between `columnconfigure`, `grid_columnconfigure`, `grid.columnconfigure`, and `grid columnconfigure` in `tkinter`? I'm getting a little confused as there seems to be either different versions of this package or different documentations floating around, e.g. [this](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/grid.htm) one that appears to be some command line/shell language with no relation to Python.

Comment: No difference, they are same I guess

Comment: Try this: `print(tkinter.Tk.columnconfigure == tkinter.Tk.grid_columnconfigure == tkinter.Grid.columnconfigure)`. It will tell you that they are the same function.

Comment: Can you point me to a source? Because there must be a reason for the difference in name and also some difference in behavior (e.g. adjusting `weight` didn't work for me with `columnconfigure`, while it did with `grid_columnconfigure`)

Comment: @michaela_karl Can you please post the code with `columnconfigure`? It is exactly the same as the other function so the arguments are the same.

Comment: @TheLizzard How can this be? I mean, is it really that the creators copy/pasted the source code for that method into two different files with differing names? Why would anyone do this if there is actually no use case for this?

Comment: @michaela_karl Also the `grid columnconfigure` is what `tkinter` calls under the hood. It's not something that you need to know. It's not really `tkinter` but `tcl`. `tkinter` is built on top of `tcl`

Comment: Imagine writing a `Frame` class that makes a certain type of frames fitting to your application...then you create two `.py` files with *slightly* different names, but identical content. And then use both methods arbitrarily. Why? Did this happen as an accident and now there are reasons why one version cannot be removed (e.g. compatibility issues)? Doesn't this just clutter the namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `tkinter`'s source code (Python 3.9 it's line 1776):

```py
class Misc:
    ...
    def grid_columnconfigure(self, index, cnf={}, **kw):
        """Configure column INDEX of a grid.

        Valid resources are minsize (minimum size of the column),
        weight (how much does additional space propagate to this column)
        and pad (how much space to let additionally)."""
        return self._grid_configure('columnconfigure', index, cnf, kw)

    columnconfigure = grid_columnconfigure
```

then on line 2499:

```py
class Grid:
    ...
    columnconfigure = grid_columnconfigure = Misc.grid_columnconfigure
```

It shows you that they are the same exact functions

The `grid columnconfigure` is actually not `tkinter` but `tcl`. It's what `tkinter` uses internally. You don't really need to know it.