# How to use grid to set widget in specific position?

Tags: python, tkinter

How to set container frame have 12 columns. then, widget button can place in specific column properly by column? in this code, i try to set clientFrame to 12 column. then, set signup btn in column 3 position, loginBtn in column 5 position.

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("1280x720")
clientFrame = tkinter.Frame(root)

signupBtn = tkinter.Button(clientFrame, text= "Signup")
signupBtn.grid(column= 3, row= 0)

loginBtn = tkinter.Button(clientFrame, text= "Login")
loginBtn.grid(column= 5, row=0)

clientFrame.grid(columnspan= 12)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try adding `padx` and/or `pady` to your `.grid()`s. Also you shouldn't really set the specific widget position. Imagine that someone is using your program from another computer that has a different screen resolution. If you really want to set the specific position you can use the `.place` manager instead of the `.grid` manager.

Comment: @TheLizzard did you mean `.place()`? (which btw can also be adjusted to be in a relative position)

Comment: @Matiiss My bad. I mistyped `.place` and turned it into `.pack` :D. Also to make more dynamic looking windows, `.pack`/`.grid` is preferred. Personally I never use `.place` unless I want the user to be able to drag a widget.

Comment: @Matiiss no, i means grid like grid in css.

Comment: @davidstephen I am not to familiar with css grid stuff but if that means that if you place sth in column 5 then all the columns are "prefilled" meaning they don't shrink then well you can use `.rowconfigure` and `.columnconfigure` (or was it .grid_rowconfigure?) and set for example the `minsize` to some value, oh and that has to prob be done in a loop because you can specify only one row or column in that method

Comment: @TheLizzard padx or pady is a margin. its not exactly grid system. have you ever code in css, table or grid? each column have own space to put something.

Comment: @Matiiss `.grid_rowconfigure` is the same as `.rowconfigure`. For more info look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68394605/11106801).

Comment: @davidstephen You can set up the margins so that the widgets appear in arbitrary places. I haven't used `css`. Also don't think of `tkinter` as a webpage. `tkinter` has 3 geometry managers that you can use: `.pack`, `.grid` and `.place`.

Comment: With `grid`, rows and columns that don't have anything in them have a size of zero.  How do you think `grid` should compute the widths of empty columns? Do you want them to be a minimum size? An identical size?

Comment: @Matiiss: _"oh and that has to prob be done in a loop because you can specify only one row or column in that method "_ - that is not true. You can specify a list of rows or columns.

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks for the info, I didn't know that (docs I were using don't describe this however, but I tested it myself)

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted does in fact put the buttons in the requested row and column. However, empty rows and empty columns have a height or width of zero so your buttons appear different than what you might expect.

It's not clear what you expect to happen when you have empty rows and columns. If you want to enforce a minimum size on each column you can do that with the `grid_columnconfigure` method and the `minsize` property. Or, you want all columns to be the same size you can set the `uniform` attribute to the same value for all columns.

In the following example, columns 0-11 are all constrained to be the same width, so they will be as wide as the widest item in any column:

```
clientFrame.grid_columnconfigure(list(range(12)), uniform="equal")
```

[image: screenshot of equal sized columns]

If instead of equal columns you want a minimum column width, this sets the minimum width of a column to 100 pixels:

```
clientFrame.grid_columnconfigure(list(range(12)), minsize=100)
```

[image: screenshot of columns with minimum width]

Comment: Are u test the code already? in Windows, all button disappears. not like result u give.

Comment: @davidstephen: yes, I tested my code. That's how I got the screenshots. The code works. There is no difference with how `grid` works on different platforms.